# Is there a simple way to check if local Storage is empty?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Q is self explanatory, just looking to check in an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try this

```
localStorage.length === 0
```

Answer (score 2):

[`localStorage` has a `length` property:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Storage)

```
if (localStorage.length === 0) {
   // empty
}
```